How to avoid of dropdown list takes full screen?
In angular, I did the data interpolation with binding three data from a JSON taken from API calling.
But in the case that drop down takes full screen to load that data. How can I change its width as user friendly way?
I tried below code in the select element?
"
Choose...
<option *ngFor="let country of countiesList">{{country.idd.root}}{{country.idd.suffixes}} {{country.name.common}}
"
Here I add three data and results give as full screen width dropdown box.
How can i fix it?

One idea is to use CSS max-width on the dropdown panel, or use text-overflow: ellipsis when your text is bigger than your width
